# Is there a way in which a normal Job server can inform a consul server that it is going down?

Tags: consul

I'm a consul neophyte. There exists certain job servers in which consul is not configured. And these job servers has to inform consul server that it is about to fail and then fail. Is there a class that I can use using rickfast's consul client?

Currently there's a simple listener on the consul server. This listener uses ConsulCache.Listener :- https://github.com/rickfast/consul-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/orbitz/consul/cache/ConsulCache.java

Haven't figured out a way yet. Any suggestions will be most welcome.